# Why does $det(R) = +1$ imply right handed frame?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, lie-algebras, rotations

Let $R$ be a rotational matrix in $SO(3)$ so it satisfies $R^TR = I$

Solvng for $det(R^TR) = (det(R))^2 = 1$ yields two solutions

Why does $det(R) = +1$ mean that the frame is a right handed frame?

What is the distinguishing feature between a left handed and right handed frame?

Comment: The determinant depends on the order of the vectors. If you swap the position of two vectors (right handed becomes left handed), the determinant changes its sign and becomes $-1$.